# How to structure a link to an address so that it opens the user's *default* maps application on their mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, html, google-maps, maps

Building a responsive web application and I want to create a link to an address that when clicked, it will open the "default" maps application on the user's device centered on that location.

So to clarify:

If the user is on an iPhone and they have Apple Maps set as their default ... I want Apple Maps to open, if they have Google Maps as their default ... I want Google Maps app to open.

Thanks

Comment: Does iOS support the `geo:` scheme for a URL?

Comment: I don't believe iOS supports setting a default maps app (at least anymore).

Comment: iOS opens `geo:` on Google Earth if it's installed, at least in my testing.